# How to dynamically create Select Options using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

**Form.php**

```
echo("<div id='myDv'>");
echo("<select id='mySelect'>");
   echo("<span id='mySpan'>");

        //here I want dynamically generated option values

   echo("</span>");
echo("</select>");
echo("</div>");
```

**myJquery.js**

```
$.post('Process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){

      $('#mySpan').html(data);// I tried, but does'nt work

}).fail(function() {alert( "Some Problem Occured" );});
```

**Process.php**

```
$strSql="SELECT Id, Title FROM mytable";
$result=mysql_query($strSql);
while($rowSet=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo("<option value=".$rowSet['Id'].">".$rowSet['Title']."</option>");
}
```

My requirement is to use the **Id** and **Title** obtained in Process.php, to create select options that will be displayed in the **Form.php**.

What changes are required in my code?
How can I access the **$rowSet** of **Process.php** in myJquery.js, to create the select options, that I want to display in Form.php

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Why don't you just json encode the data from server side then Put it back into select  onchange Event of jquery or javascript .

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side Processing**

File Name:***Process.php***

First we fetch Data using same query as you have written above

```
$data=array();
$strSql="SELECT Id, Title FROM mytable";
$result=mysql_query($strSql);
while($rowSet=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $option=array("id"=>$rowSet["Id"],"Title"=>$rowSet["Title"]);
   $data[]=$option;
}
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

**Client Side Processing** 
I am using jquery and  its change event.I am looping json encoded data to extract Id and Title from them.

```
    <select id="getOptions"></select>
    <script>
    $("#getOptions").change(function(e){
     $.ajax({
        url:"Process.php",
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
       for(var i=0;i>=data.length;i++){
        $("#getOptions").append("<option value='"+data[i]["Id"]+"'>"+data[i]["Title"]+"    </option>");
       }
      },
    error:function(err){
     alert(err);
      }
    });
});
    </script>
```